# How to access Button inside Activity from Fragment

Tags: java, android

How to access Button inside Activity from Fragment. Actually I set myButton is disabled but when some of my radioButtons was clicked i want to set myButton enabled?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an example:

In MyFragment.java

```
public MyFragment extends Fragment {
    public interface Callback {
        public void onRadioButtonClicked(View radioButton);
    }

    private Callback callback;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity ac) {
        super.onAttached(ac);
        callback = (Callback)ac;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        callback = null;
        super.onDetach();
    }

    ....
    ....
       radioButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(View view) {
               if (callback != null) {
                   callback.onRadioButtonClicked(view);
               }
           }
       });
}
```

And in MyActivity.java that hosts/contains a MyFragment:

```
public MyActivity extends Activity implements MyFragment.Callback {

    ...
    @Override
    public void onRadioButtonClicked(View radioButton) {
        // The radiobutton in MyFragment has been clicked
        myButton.setEnabled(true); // or something like this.
    }

}
```

This design uses the `MyFragment.Callback` interface to keep details of the hosting Activity away from the Fragment, allowing the Fragment to be hosted by any Activity as long as the Activity implements `MyFragment.Callback`.

Answer (score 5):

There are a few things you could try. The first one is to use `getActivity().findViewByIt(id)` to get the `Button`, which I think should work but it's not a good solution from the engineering side of things since your `Fragment` would make assumptions about the `Activity` layout that hosts it. The second would be to provide a callback interface as described [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#CommunicatingWithActivity). Just call the callback method every time the checkbox changes state. This approach is better since the `Fragment` can be freely re-used by any activity that implements the callback interface. Last but not least, you should try to put the `Button` inside the fragment if at all possible.

Comment: Don't let the Fragment be depending on the Activity. That is bad design. The Fragment could be hosted by another Activity. Use a proper callback mechanism instead. Ah, stripe that. I see you mention the callback interface as well.